# Eslint error when using the for in loop how to restructure

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am getting `iterators/generators require regenerator-runtime, which is too heavyweight for this guide to allow them. Separately, loops should be avoided in favor of array iterations` error when using the following line of code

```
 const errors = {};
      for (const i of err.inner) {
        errors[i.path] = i.message;
      }
```

How can I restructure the code to remove this error
Thanks

Comment: Please post what eslint error you get?

Comment: Its in the description

Comment: try `forEach`. It's the rule `no-restricted-syntax` that makes it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```js
let errors = {};

err.inner.forEach(item => {
   errors[item.path] =  item.message;
});
```

Comment: Worked charmingly

Comment: @SImonHaddad if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Comment: Done, I though the upper arrow was meant to do that. Thanks alot